# Función allow="autoplay" no trabaja

Tags: html, html5, stream

Tengo un reproductor **html5** de una radio online, la idea es que reproduzca de forma automática apenas cargue la web. Probé varios atributos y no funcionan.

Este es el código:

```html
<iframe name="contenedorPlayer" class="cuadroBordeado" allow="autoplay" width="100%" height="110px" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no src="https://cp.usastreams.com/html5-player-barra-responsive.aspx?stream=http://209.126.119.28:8663/;&fondo=07&formato=mp3&color=5&titulo=2&autoStart=1&vol=5&nombre=La+mejor+radio&imagen=http://www.lanotastereo.com.co/images/logook.png"><a href="https://www.usastreams.com/" alt = "Usastreams.com posicionamiento web, Servicios SEO y SEM, servicios streaming" title="hosting radio gratis autodj ,internet streaming de tv ,Streaming Audio para Radio Online ,Crear Radio En Internet,">hosting radio ,streaming hosting tv</a></iframe>
```

Agradezco la ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: vuelve a revisar por que yo probé tu código y se reproduce de manera automática apenas carga la web

Comment: Así es pero cuando se cierra y se vuelve abrir deja de trabajar. :(

Comment: a mí me sale el error `jquery.jplayer.min.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException _html_play @ jquery.jplayer.min.js:3` apenas carga

Answer (score 0):

somos los creadores del player, en usastreams.com, el player en chrome, por su nueva politica, solo trabaja en automatico cuando el asuario le da play un par de veces. en los demas navegadores no hay problema.